# Why is the width and height of the SVG text that a browser renders inconsistent with the width and height in the font file?

Tags: svg, text, browser

I use a lot of font design tools to read the width and height of the font, and the width and height of my svg text rendering in the browser seem to be inconsistent?

What causes the browser to have extra white space?

Here's an example [image: text]

How to calculate his true height without operating dom?

Answer (score 1):

Fonts have to allow for characters to descend below the line of the font e.g. p, y, g. That portion of the letter that descends below the normal line of the font is called a [descender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)

Equally fonts can have parts e.g. accents that render above the normal top of most letters called [ascenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography))

Just because the letters you've picked have neither, doesn't mean the font doesn't allow for them. You wouldn't want your text to shift about just because you add one extra letter that happens to contain either an ascender or descender.

There's a [Font Metrics API in canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) that might be useful if you want to get this information but SVG provides no APIs that would get this information.

Comment: Can I use the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.measureText` method to get a width that is inconsistent than the browser rendering?